# Possible to set all App pools/Websites on an IIS 6 and/or IIS 7 server to 4.0 instead of 3.5 at one time?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, asp.net

Is it possible to set all App pools/Websites on an IIS 6 and/or IIS 7 server to 4.0 instead of 3.5 *in one fell swoop*?

Basically we have many servers, and will be upgrading all them 4.0 from 3.5. Right clicking and changing each site would be rather cumbersome. The servers are a mix of IIS 6 and IIS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `appcmd.exe` coupled with `PSEXEC.exe`.

```
psexec.exe @file="c:\path\to\file\with\allserverx.txt" %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD.exe set apppool /apppool.name:www.mysite.com /managedRuntimeVersion:4.0
```